# LiveDataScope vs ViewModelScope in Android

Tags: android, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I was reading how to use coroutines here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines. What makes me confused about is the difference between `LiveDataScope` and `ViewModelScope`. It sounds like `ViewModelScope` takes care of lifecycle automatically and you can do network request in the block. When data received from server, post the value to `livedata`. but then when I continued to read, there's another topic about `LiveDataScope` which seems redundant to me since you can already accomplish the same result by using `ViewModelScope` with `livedata`. What is the main difference between those two? and when should I choose to use one over the other?

Comment: livedata builder actually

Comment: Okay, then you misunderstood that. both things are actually bound with `lifecycle.coroutineScope` which provides `CoroutineContext`. So, when you've some suspended function from repository, you can directly declare it in to LiveData builder which inherits same lifecycle from LifecycleOwner from which your ViewModel is for an instance.

Comment: I think what I get really confused about is after reading https://medium.com/corouteam/exploring-kotlin-coroutines-and-lifecycle-architectural-components-integration-on-android-c63bb8a9156f, sounds like `livedata` builder is meant to replace `ViewModelScope` + `LiveData`? if `livedata` is the only type of variable I have in `ViewModel`, is `livedata` builder itself good enough?

Comment: actually, what's confusing to me the most is that `livedata builder` looks like a replacement of `ViewModelScope` + `livedata`

Comment: @JeelVankhede What does your answer mean?  Can you please provide an example

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Note:** This might be late answer for this topic if **Author of OP** already has understanding about this, But providing some pointers for the referencing comment of @IgorGanapolsky.

---

Let's see what is the main difference between [**viewModelScope**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#viewmodelscope) & [**LiveDataScope**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LiveDataScope)

### 1. viewModelScope:

> Official doc says that, `CoroutineScope` tied to this `ViewModel`. This
>   scope will be canceled when `ViewModel` will be cleared, i.e
>   `ViewModel.onCleared` is called

Meaning that **coroutine scope is tied to ViewModel**, and once ViewModel gets cleared this scope gets destroyed by cancelling all child coroutine jobs.

Basically, in MVVM pattern we use `ViewModel` tied to a particular `Activity/Fragment`.  So once that `Activity/Fragment` gets destroyed, its `ViewModel` reaches a cleared state. Thus, it cancels all incomplete jobs **started by `viewModelScope`**, throwing `CancellationException`.

So a **usecase of `viewModelScope`** is: inside `ViewModel` when you've got any suspended function to be called and need a `CoroutineScope`, inspite of making new one you can directly use this one out of the box from **viewodel-ktx** library.

```
class SomeViewModel: ViewModel() {

    fun someFunction() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            callingSomeSuspendedFun()
            callingAnotherSuspendedFun()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly override `onCleared()` method of `ViewModel` to cancel the scope, it does automatically for you, cheers!

### 2. LiveDataScope:

Now speaking of `LiveDataScope`, it's actually an interface provided to build better support for `LiveData/CoroutineLiveData` that can have `CoroutineScope` out of the box! use **livedata-ktx** version

Now imagine a situation that you're having a MVVM pattern and wanted to return `LiveData` from repository to view model. your repository also contains some suspended functions and some coroutine scope.

In that situation when you do some suspended method calls & return the result as live data, there would be some extra work. you'll need transform your data to particular live data after getting it as result. see the example below:

```
class SomeRepository {

    suspended fun someApiCall() : LiveData<Result> {
        val result = MutableLiveData<Result>()
        someCoroutineScope.launch {
            val someData = someOtherCallToGetResult()
            result.postValue(someData) 
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Imagine you had to write above code block due to `LiveData` didn't had any support for Coroutines ... **but until now!**

Now you can directly use `liveData { }` function that returns you `LiveData` object giving you scope of `LiveDataScope` in such a way that you can continue your suspended work and emit the result at the same level rather than getting it messy way like above. So above code block can now optimized by following code or better:

```
class SomeRepository {

    suspended fun someApiCall() : LiveData<Result> {
        return liveData<Result> {
            val someData = someOtherCallToGetResult()
            emit(someData)
        }
    }
}
```

So use case of liveData would be at repository level when using MVVM pattern if you expose LiveData to viewmodel from respository rather than creating new inside viewmodel. Please note that there's no thumb rule about `liveData` method shouldn't be used at viewmodel directly. You can if you want to avoid `viewModelScope` completely.

---

### TL;DR

Check out the [**liveData**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) method,

> Doc states that, The `liveData` building block serves as a
>   **structured concurrency primitive** between coroutines and `LiveData`. The code block starts executing when `LiveData` becomes
>   active and is automatically canceled after a configurable timeout when
>   the `LiveData` becomes inactive. If it is canceled before completion,
>   it is restarted if the `LiveData` becomes active again. If it
>   completed successfully in a previous run, it doesn't restart. Note
>   that it is restarted only if canceled automatically. If the block is
>   canceled for any other reason *(e.g. throwing a
>   `CancelationException`)*, it is not restarted.

I hope that make sense!

Comment: Does this API meet structured concurrency (https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-anniversary-f2cc748b2401) as set forth by JetBrains?  Or do we also need to use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`

Comment: When you need some critical IO operation you'll need to change context as both of them provides main context.

Comment: Please note that you should **not** use LiveData in your repository, as it runs on the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

The names imply what they actually are:

> A ViewModelScope is defined for each ViewModel in your app. Any
>   coroutine launched in this scope is automatically canceled if the
>   ViewModel is cleared.

This means that you can do some tasks(like continuous processing) in a coroutine that is in the scope of the ViewModel. The advantage is that you don't have to care anymore when the ViewModel will be stopped to stop your coroutine (this is a big pain when working with global things like java threads). The lifecycle of the ViewModel is related to when an activity is **ended**.

The `LiveDataScope` is used for emitting values in the scope of a `LiveData` object. This means that as long as the `LiveData` object is alive and there are subscribers that coroutine will work, however once all the subscribers are out the coroutine will stop. This coroutine also restarts once the `LiveData` is active again.

Basically these are 2 coroutine contexts each responsible for the lifecycle of its element.

**PS:**

> It sounds like ViewModelScope takes care of lifecycle automatically
>   and you can do network request in the block.

First of all, network requests cannot be done from the Main thread, you usually do them from IO scope, you can read [more here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-dispatcher/index.html). The second thing is that you should take a look at the lifecycle of the ViewModel compared to Activity if you want to understand why `LiveDataScope` is usually combined with `ViewModelScope`, you can read about that [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle).

The short answer to your question is that you cannot be sure that the view is created from the `ViewModelScope` so if you want to push some updates to UI you should push them as long as someone is subscribed to LiveData, this is where the `LiveDataScope` comes into play.

Comment: thank you for the explanation Daniel. Am I right to understand it this way. Assume my `ViewModel` has just `LiveData` and I'm using it to request date from server and also assume we are in a wonderful world that threading is all taken care of. I can utilize `ViewModelScope` to fetch data then post value to `livedata`, or I can use `livedata builder` to fetch data

Comment: When is LiveDataScope preferable over ViewModelScope? It seems redundant to use both.  Especially when we have `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` - which meets this objective of structured concurrency

Comment: as mentioned at the end of the answer, LiveDataScope is preferred when you push updates to the UI, since ViewModelScope is not cancelled on config change. It was introduced specifically to avoid a lot of boilerplate code, witch applications written in java have a lot of.