# What's the proper way to use Coroutines in Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

For viewModels we can use

```
 viewModelScope.launch {
     //long running operation
 }
```

this is the proper way for viewModel.

Same like this, what's the best way to launch coroutines in Activity?

I used GlobalScope launch in Activity, is it right approach?

```
GlobalScope.launch {

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For activities you should use `lifecycleScope`

Read more about it in the official documentation:

[Use Kotlin coroutines with lifecycle-aware components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)

Answer (score 1):

ViewModelScope by default run on main thread [viewModelScope launch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62507129/7248394).

For Global Scope, read this answer which perfectly explain when to use
[Global scope launch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54336168/7248394).